# Android Studio debug "View Bitmap" downscaled

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, bitmap, preview

I am having an issue with the "View Bitmap" preview functionality of Android Studio. I am having a bitmap with 29000 and height 255. But when I click "View Bitmap" in the debugger on the Bitmap class, i see a downscaled version. Yes i am aware that 29k width is a lot, but it was working with Android Studio < 1.5, so i guess its a setting somewhere.

Here is the info about the Bitmap in the Debugger view

[image: debugger bitmap]

And here is the Bitmap when i click on "View Bitmap".

[image: bitmap]

As you see the dimensions are not right. That debug preview bitmap is way smaller than the one i want to see.

**Any suggestion how to fix that?**

Comment: maybe this would help: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: well, the bitmap is working okay in my application. the only thing is the debug view does not work anymore

Comment: and what happen if you use zoom in, is it changing to your size?

Comment: yep.. it just zoom in to the 1024x8 bitmap.. thats all.. resolution stays same all the time :/

Comment: trying to find a similar problem, but there is not any like that. Tough luck :-/

Comment: For anyone wondering, this is still present in Studio 3.1.2. I suspect it scales down images so that their largest dimension is 1024 at most. Rather disappointing, I see no reason why we can't pull full size images from the device.