# Why does Bitmap.createBitmap return a Bitmap with a different size than specified and how to avoid it?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas, bitmap

When I create a `Bitmap` and `Canvas` with the following code:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

and I put a breakpoint at the second line to display the preview, it turns out the created `Bitmap`'s size is different than specified. It's supposed to be `640px` wide, but the preview says it's `377px` instead.

The height is scaled down by the same factor (`640/377` is the same as `1737/1024`) so I presume some unwanted scaling takes place there.

[image: Android Studio debugger]

Interestingly, `bitmap.getWidth()` returns `640`.

I initially thought it might be the debugger's preview related issue, but I checked that when I load some images using:

```java
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.image)
```

and I scale them later to the desired width:

```java
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, desiredWidthPx, targetHeightToKeepAspectRatio, false)
```

the debugger's preview shows them correctly, i.e. their size matches `desiredWidthPx` and `targetHeightToKeepAspectRatio`. So it's not the preview's issue.

For context: I stumbled upon this issue while working on a `Bitmap` with a specific width in pixels. The `Bitmap` is going to be printed by a thermal printer later on, so the size must not depend on the Android device's screen size, density and so on. I started debugging  this issue after realizing the printer printed around 60% of the image (it was cropped horizontally), e.g. something like this:

[image: Printed paper]

I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but by looking at the printouts, I think it's reasonable to suspect the scaling to be the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmap size in the debug preview is limited to 1024px regardless of the method used to create it. Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620813/android-studio-debug-view-bitmap-downscaled) and [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150153784). Your issue with the printer is not related to it.

Comment: Wow, it's so surprising. It seems you are right. I confirmed it by scaling a bitmap to anything beyond 1024px and checking the preview. The issue must be somewhere else in that case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BufferedImage instead:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html